# TSplitter by Source code move

Tags: delphi

On my form I placed a TSplitter and two panels . Running the programm I can move the size of the 2 pannels using the Splitter between these panels.

I Would like to move the splitter by my source code, but all my attemps failed

```
  procedure ChangeGUILayout (....);
  var 
  aNewValue : Integer;


  begin

  MySpliiter.left := aNewValue;

  ....
```

Answer (score 10):

You shoudn't mess with the splitter, but with the control that is aligned and fixed-sized.

For example, say that you have two panels. `Panel1` is `alLeft` and `Panel2` is `alClient`. In between you have a splitter. Then you want

```
Panel1.Width := aNewValue;
```

Comment: +1 It's not so much that you shouldn't mess with the splitter, more that you can't readily manipulate the splitters position through code. The way you would have to do it would be to fake mouse move messages! So, do what the splitter itself does, and modify the bounds of the controls that the splitter manages.